# White space covering default text

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In my textarea, I have a default text in the textarea. However, whenever I first go onto the page, the default text is covered with a layer of white. When I go in to delete the white layer on top, it reveals my default text right below. Here is my code included below:

```
<div class="form-bottom" style="margin-top: 30px">
    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('feedbacks') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <textarea id="feedbacks" class="form-control" name="feedbacks"
                      placeholder="Please include a detailed description of your idea and experience"
                      rows="10" style="width: 600px">
            </textarea>
            @if ($errors->has('feedbacks'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('feedbacks') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
```

[The picture of my textarea with the white layer on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgJSV.png)

[The picture of my textarea with the white layer highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cpiH.png)

[The picture of my textarea after I highlight the white area and delete it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ribpa.png)

Comment: You also need to explain how you implemented it. It's not a general but your implementation problem, so you don't have choice but provide more details.

Comment: How can we possibly know what's going on without seeing the source code? (Source code should be included _as text, directly in your question_.) Please read [ask].

Comment: There's probably a tab in your `<textarea ...></textarea>` tag.

Comment: @ccKep with such a guesses you're significantly decreasing the chance OP provides any details (I'm not insisting or patronising though, it's just my observation that as soon as people started guessing - the OP's attention is drifting towards those guesses and the community just wastes time)

Comment: @zerkms It's an educated guess, OP using an IDE which indents tags and probably put the `</textarea>` onto the next line - there's not much else that could be at work here.

Comment: @ccKep yep, it's a good guess, sorry :-)

Comment: @JenniferZhou Please replace the picture of your code by your actual code (in text form, as zerkms suggested) - I'll add the answer to your problem afterwards. This helps future users who have the same problem to find this question/answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments: You have your `</textarea>` ending tag in a new line.

Your IDE indents that using spaces or tabs, which in the case of a textarea are considered its contents.

Change

```
                            <textarea id="feedbacks" class="form-control" name="feedbacks"
                                      placeholder="Please include a detailed description of your idea and experience"
                                      rows="10" style="width: 600px">
                                </textarea>
```

To

```
                            <textarea id="feedbacks" class="form-control" name="feedbacks"
                                      placeholder="Please include a detailed description of your idea and experience"
                                      rows="10" style="width: 600px"></textarea>
```

And you're fine (note the `</textarea>` ending tag **immediately** after the opening tag)